# Append to an existing file without overwrite from psql command \o

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am connected to my database (i.e. analysis) with psql, and from there I know if I do:

```
\o 'C/MYDIRECTORIES/test.csv'
SELECT * FROM test;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

I can continuously append content to this `test.csv` file until I run `\o` again to quit the export.

However, after some time, if I want to append new stuff into this `test.csv` and if I do `\o 'C/MYDIRECTORIES/test.csv'` again, `test.csv` will be wiped out first. In another word, I lost my previously saved content.

I did some search online, I found this link ([Using psql \o to append to a file](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/03/using-o-to-append-to-file/)). It offers a solution to my question. However, when I ran its suggested command:

```
\o | cat - >> 'C/MYDIRECTORIES/test.csv'
```

an error pops out like: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. I double checked my path and it is correct. Can anyone help to take a look at this issue?

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Note that the blog post mentioned in the question, "Using psql \o to append to a file", has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2010/03/using-o-to-append-to-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this command is for UNIX, and you seem to be using Windows.

You could try and find a replacement that works on Windows, but that is notoriously difficult unless you want to write a `cmd` script that does it for you.

I'll make an attempt here, but I have no Windows nearby, so it's guesswork and you'll have to debug it:

```
\o | CMD /D /C TYPE CON >> 'C:\\MYDIRECTORIES\\test.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, just tried this and gave the same error message, but at least I now know why the online resource example didn't work for my attempt.

Comment: If the \o way is too hard for windows, do you have any thoughts for my purpose to append content to an existing output without overwrite it by postgresql? I know there're other route such as Python can do this job, but just wanna explore further on postgresql, thanks.

Comment: I'd write a powershell script that appends its standard input to a file and use that with `\o |`.